# JQuery Dialog Modal Popup worked yesterday but not today

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I am using JQuery Dialog's Modal Popup functionality and have been using it for probably 5-6 months now.  I have never had any problems with it working until today.  Everything works on my computer fine, but a different employee is getting JQuery errors and the popup won't display.  It was working for him yesterday and no changes have been committed to the code base.

I'm using Chromes inspect element option and the errors hes getting are things like "('div') does not have 'parent()' function".  I understand what this error means but I have no idea why its showing up in the first place.  All the rest of the computers I've checked are working fine.  Also, it's not browser related.  Broke in IE, FF and Chrome.

I know there was a windows update this morning for me, but I can't imagine a windows update would break JQuery's functionality.  Any thoughts on what else could be happening here?

```
function ModalPopup(divId, parentId, isExtender) {
if (isExtender == "True") {
    ModalPopupExtender(parentId, divId);
    return;
}

var div = document.getElementById(divId);

//Disable any datepickers on the popup otherwise they will display on load
var datePickers = $(div).find("input[class='datePicker hasDatepicker']");
datePickers.each(function (index) {
    $(this).datepicker('disable');
});

//Find the buttons on the div
var buttons = $(div).find("input[type='submit']");
buttons.each(function (index) {

    $(this).click(function () {
        Cancel(divId);
        //$(div).dialog("close");
    });

    $(this).attr("style", "padding:5px; margin:5px; color:#696969; background-color:#EEE; border-radius:6px;");
});

//Create a footer div, add the buttons to the div
$footerDiv = $('<div style="height:40px;" />');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    $footerDiv.append(buttons[i]);
}

//Add a canel button that closes the popu
$cancelBtn = $('<input type="button" style="padding:5px; margin:5px; color:#696969; background-color:#EEE; border-radius:6px;" value="Cancel" onclick="Cancel(\'' + divId + '\')" />');
$footerDiv.append($cancelBtn);

//Display the div with the info
$(div).attr("style", "display:block; font-size: 11px;");

//Display the dialog box
$(div).dialog({ minWidth: 300,
    minHeight: 150,
    maxHeight: 400,
    draggable: false,
    resizeable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons:
    {
        'Cancel': function () {
            $(div).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    open: function (e, ui) {
        $(e.target).parent().find('span').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text() === 'Cancel';
        }).parent().replaceWith($footerDiv);

        //Adjust the width for IE
        var version = getInternetExplorerVersion();
        if (version != -1 && version < 8.0) {
            $(e.target).dialog('option', 'width', ($(e.target)[0].scrollWidth + 50) + 'px');
        }
        else
            $(e.target).dialog('option', 'width', 'auto');

        //Adjust the height if the dialog is too big
        if ($(div).height() > 800)
            $(e.target).dialog('option', 'height', 800);
        $(e.target).dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
    }
});

//Hide the title bar
$(div).dialog().parents(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
$(div).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));

//Enable the datepickers again after the dialog has opened
datePickers.each(function (index) {
    $(this).datepicker('enable');
});

//Style any select boxes to be the width of their container
$(div).find("select:[multiple]").each(function () {
    $(this).width("100%");
});
```

}

**Edit** Also of note, if I click the button to display the popup it gives me a quick error message and then just refreshes the page.

Comment: could you please post some code so to help identify the issue?

Comment: Why dont you add your code, I rarely beleive in magic when it comes to code errors...

Comment: I'll post what I have but I don't think its code related. It's only a single computer of hundreds running the same site.

Comment: Have to go and find it now lol it's been a long time since I even looked at it.

Comment: windows update? ... a restart shouldn't be enough. Shut the pc down (I could write a book about more than 15 years of Windows' weird things ;)

Comment: there was a chrome update today as well , or yesterday , depending on how often you use the browser

Comment: @ScottSelby it broke in IE too, as well as FF so I think browser issues are out of the question.